# How to call a functor from another member function of the same class?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, functor

I have overloaded the () operator to do the comparison for me and I want to send that as the comparator to the third argument of the std sort function call. Now, this call is in another member function called `threeSum`. I found that sending it `Solution()` works but `this()` doesn't work. What are the syntax rules for this?

```
class Solution 
{
public:    
    bool operator() (int i, int j)
    {
        return (i < j);
    }

    vector<vector<int> > threeSum(vector<int> & nums) 
    {
        sort(nums.begin(), nums.end(), this());

        vector<vector<int> > ret_vec;
        ...
        return ret_vec;
    }
};
```

Thank you.

Comment: Where should I rather have the comparator?

Comment: `sort(nums.begin(), nums.end(), std::ref(*this));` You may need to make the operator `const`, as in `bool operator() (int i, int j) const {...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `this()` doesn't work is because `this` is a pointer. You need to dereference it first.

```
(*this)(args);
```

In your case, you should write this:

```
sort(nums.begin(), nums.end(), (*this));
```

Or, if you want to be more explicit:

```
Solution& this_val = *this;
sort(nums.begin(), nums.end(), this_val);
```

Comment: Calling `operator()` with `1` and `2` doesn't make sense, `std::sort` has to call it with 2 different arguments to be able to sort them.

Comment: I was trying to give a more general answer, but I have updated it to match the question more exactly.

Comment: Neither `(*this)()` nor `this_val()` would compile.

Comment: Ah, it needs the real functor - fixed.

Answer (score 1):

A non-static member function (including any functor) requires the address of the containing object as its implicit argument. You could use a lambda function to achieve the effect:

```
vector<vector<int> > threeSum(vector<int> & nums) 
{
  auto mysort = [this](int i, int j) {
    return operator()(i, j); 
  };
  sort(nums.begin(), nums.end(), mysort);
  ...
}
```

Here the lambda function `mysort` captures the run-time address of the containing object (`this`) and use it as an implicit argument to `operator()`, which can now be used by `std::sort`.

EDIT: This method will not only work for functors but other member functions as well. But if you only want to use the functor for sorting, then the other answer which provides `(*this)` directly as the 3rd argument to `sort` might be slightly more efficient.